# Jupyter Notebook not opening (ImportError: DLL load failed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I hope everyone is doing good.

I installed **Python** a couple of days ago and then I install **Anaconda3 2019**.

Here is the screenshot of my programs installed on my system.

[image: Installed programs on System]

Now when I am trying to work on Jupyter, it is not opening. I tried to open **Jupyter Notebook** directly from the start (It showed a terminal opening and closing but after that, Localhost couldn't start). Later I tried through **Anaconda Prompt** and it gives me this Error.

[image: Main Error]

**conda list** command shows that Jupyter library is present but I don't know where the problem lies.

[image: Conda List Command]

These are the paths Environment variable has:

[image][image]

[image: Enviorment Variable]

I'm a newbie and playing with python, Jupyter. I will appreciate it if anyone can help me to solve this issue I'm currently facing.

**Thanks & Regards**

**Umar**

**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Tried Suggestions >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

Running Command **conda install nb_conda** produced this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

```
conda activate <env_name>

conda install ipykernel

ipython kernel install --name <env_name> --user
```

If you are working on base environment, you can specify env_name as base.

Try running jupyter notebook using the command `jupyter notebook`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Lakshmi for your response. I tried it, but still facing the same issue... :(

Comment: Could you please check the Path environment variable in control panel. Control Panel\System and Security\System ===> Edit the system environment variables ==> Advanced ==>Environment variables.Set Path as "C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\Scripts"

Comment: I have edited the question and added Environment Variable screenshots. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok..Now in a new command prompt if you activate the environment , and give the command jupyter notebook, are you getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your anaconda prompt and type the command `conda install nb_conda`.

Let this install and then try running the command `jupyter notebook`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried **conda install nb_conda** and it gave me an error. I have posted error with a screenshot in my question.